# how to regenerate an array after removing elements ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Poorly worded question I know, if someone can suggest a reword then I'd be happy to change.

What I am trying explain is this...
Let's say you go through an iteration 10 times, yet the array contains only five entries. on the 6th iteration you want a new array with repleted values. how do you do that?

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
10.times do 
 foo = Foo.new
 foo.bar = array.pop
end
```

I am sure this is very simple.

## Update

```
School::YEARS = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012] 
        @array = School::YEARS #this contains five elements
        10.times do |x|
         classroom = School.new
         classroom.year = @array.pop
        end
=>2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012
```

so here i want a new array containing the same five elements as it did before the iteration began.

Comment: What should the "fresh array" contain?  Could you add a `puts` statement somewhere and say what the desired output of the program is?  I also recommend removing `Foo` since you didn't define what it is.

Comment: What is a "fresh array"?  In your updated example, why do you assign a new School object to the "classroom" variable and then immediately overwrite that value with the next member of the `@array`?  Take some time to clearly express your problem in plain english so that others may help you.

Comment: @maerics I have changed my answer

Comment: @user3868832: Esta bien. La cosa más importante es que expresas la problema en lengua claro! Ese no es una problema fácil ;-)

Comment: Please just say the input you have (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5) and the desired output you want (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5) and leave the details to us.  It does not take much English to do that.

Comment: @maerics buena cita!!!

Comment: showed my wanted output, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidGrayson suggests, consider using the [Ruby `Array#cycle` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-cycle).  However, given your desired usage you might want to use its [`Enumerator` object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html) directly:

```
years = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012] 
repeated_years = years.cycle.each
10.times do
  classroom = School.new
  classroom.year = repeated_years.next
end
```

**[Edit]** Or, if you would simply like an array of ten values based on repeated values from your source array, you can use the `cycle` method like so:

```
years = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012] 
repeated_years = years.cycle(2).to_a
repeated_years # => [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012]
```

Comment: this is very helpful. i apologise for poor clarity and thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Would this do what you want?

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.cycle.first(10).each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

This should output the following numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: What output are you looking for and why does my answer not work?

Comment: sorry david, i have cleared my question above. thank you for your patience